# Can I view my PC localhost test site on my android tablet without uploading it?

Tags: localhost, testing, responsive-webdesign, cross-platform

I am working on a web site which is running on my PC via XAMPP.  I want to test the site on my android tablet (galaxy tab) to make sure that the responsive design behaves that way it is designed to.  I am wondering if there is a way to connect my tablet to my PC in a way that will allow me to view my localhost site on my tablet.  This would allow me to fix bugs without having to upload every change.

Comment: I think it can be possible if your PC and your tablet are in the same network (WIFI for instance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the PC and tablet are on the same network, it is possible. All you'd need to do is use the IP address of the PC to access the site. So instead of accessing it via `localhost` (as you would on the PC), you'd access it via `192.168.1.2` (example).

If the devices are not on the same network, it's still possible to access the PC with the tablet if you setup whatever router the PC is behind to port-forward port 80 requests to the PC hosting the web site/app.